# The degree of the Gauss map of Theta divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

Let $R$ be compact a Riemann surface of genus $g$ and $ J (R) $ be its Jacobian. 
For a subvariety $X$ of $J(R)$ of dimension $d$, denote the set of non-singular points of $X$ by $X_{reg}$. Then the Gauss map of $X$ can be written as 
$$
\begin{array}{llll}
G:&X_{reg}&\longrightarrow&(\mathbb{P}^{g-1})^* \\
&x&\longrightarrow& \mathbb P[T_x(X_{reg})]\\
\end{array}
$$ here $(\mathbb{P}^{g-1})^*$ is the dual projective of $\mathbb{P}^{g-1}$, that is, $(\mathbb{P}^{g-1})^*$ identified with the set of hyperplanes in $\mathbb{P}^{g-1}$.

Let's say I want to calculate the degree of the Gauss map above. I'm following Principles of Algebraic Geometry, Griffiths and Harris and also Advances in 
Moduli Theory, Shimizu and Ueno.

It follows from facts proven in the cited references that $G(X_{reg})$  is a set of points of $(\mathbb{P}^{g-1})^*$ corresponding to hyperplanes of $\mathbb{P}^{g-1} $ with certain properties $P_1$, and in addition also $\overline{G(X_{reg})}= (\mathbb{P}^{g-1})^*$, to Zariski closure of $G(X_{reg})$ . As I said, I would like to calculate the degree of the Gauss map $G$, so the references calculate $\#G^{-1}(H)$, at where $H \in G(X_{reg}) \subset (\mathbb{P}^{g-1})^*$. I imagined that first, we would need to verify that $ H $ is not a branch point of $G$, but this is not done in the references. What they actually do is take $H \in A \subset G(X_{reg})$, where $A$ is a dense open subset of $(\mathbb{P}^{g-1})^*$ that has certain properties $P_2 \subset P_1$.Thus, taken $H \in A$ is then calculated $\#G^{-1}(H)$. Only in future steps do the references verify that $H \in A$  is not a branch point of $G$.

Why is this correct? That is, why do not you need, in this case, to verify that $H \in A$  is not a branch point of $G$, before calculating $\#G^{-1}(H)$? It would be because $A$ is a dense open subset of $(\mathbb{P}^{g-1})^*$??

Thanks!

Comment: I think you want $d=g-1$ here.

Comment: for a more careful treatment of the gauss map on the theta divisor, and the consequent proof of Torelli, look at arbarello, cornalba, griffiths, harris, vol 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have answered your own question in the last paragraph.  Since the complement $U$ of the branch divisor of $G$ is a nonempty Zariski-open subset of $(\mathbb{P}^{g-1})^{\ast},$ the same is true of $U \cap A$, and if ${\#}G^{-1}(H)$ is equal to a constant $e$ for all $H \in A,$ it is equal to $e$ for all $H \in U \cap A$, and thus for all $H \in U.$

Comment: First, thank you for having responded. So ... I do not understand why you use the set $U=\{$ branch divisors of $G \}^c$. When you say " the same is true of $U \cap A$". I already knew from the information that the set $A$ is a dense open subset of $(\mathbb{P}^{g-1})^*$.  In addition, if $U \cap A \neq \emptyset $, then $A \not\subset \{$branch points of $G\}$. And then, back to the beginning of my question .... I should know this before calculating $\#G^{-1}(H)$?

Comment: Since the restriction to $G$ of $G^{-1}(U)$ is an unramified covering of $U,$ the degree of $G$ is equal to ${\#}G^{-1}(H)$ for all $H \in U.$  As a result, we only need to compute ${\#}G^{-1}(H)$ for _one_ $H \in U$, and in the proof you describe this $H$ comes to us an element of $U \cap A.$  You should know this before calculating ${\#}G^{-1}(H)$ for this particular $H$ in order to know that it computes the degree of $G.$

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble finding a reference to read about divisors in projective varieties  (since I'm very new to the subject), usually I find only for Riemann surface. So, can you give me a reference ... I need to think more about the set $U$, So, can you give me a reference ... I need to think more about the set $ U $ you use. I should not keep thinking about branch divisor of $G$, as if  $G$ were a map betwenn Riemann surfaces.

Comment: If I may suggest some, maybe Hartshorne II.6, Mumford *yellow book) 6.1,6.2, Shafarevich 3.1; and the paper by Andreotti on Torelli's theorem in Am.J.Math, especially for branch divisors of rational maps.

Comment: The answer to my question is given directly in "On a theorem of Torelli". Beginning in the section you refer to "7.The branch locus of a rational map." and finishing precisely at the beginning of the next section, section 8. Thanks!